# Php interact with python daemon - file permissions

Tags: php, python, linux, permissions, daemon

I got a python daemon running on my raspberry pi (as user pi), and I want to change its settings - which are saved in json files - via php.

It occurred to me, that I would have to either:

- change the permissions of every file i create with python or php to something like 0666
- change the owner to pi and the group www-data - for every file
- run the daemon as www-data
- create a new user and run both php and the daemon as this user

None of these really feels 'right'...

What would be the best/a good practice to do this?
(or is this way of interaction "wrong"? )

Comment: or just put `pi` and `www-data` users into a new group and x6x the files?

Comment: Maybe run the PHP file with suExex or suPHP?